# Getting a list of users on a windows machine?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm trying to return, or in this example print out each user that has been created on a windows machine, I don't really care about the windows users like "defaultuser0", but if anyone can tell me how I can exclude them aswell, that would be great, but back to the main question.

I have this code below, and it works to a certain degree. Output I received was this.

> \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC_NAME",Name="admin"
>   \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC_NAME",Name="Administrator"
>   \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC_NAME",Name="DefaultAccount"
>   \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC_NAME",Name="defaultuser0"
>   \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="PC_NAME",Name="Guest"
>   \PC_NAME\root\cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="HEAVEN",Name="WDAGUtilityAccount"

Now I understand that this is natural behaviour of my code. Is there a way I can get the actual usernames, without including the domain and all the other directory code?

Here is the code I'm using.

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount"));

foreach (var managementBaseObject in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine(((ManagementObject) managementBaseObject).ToString());
}
```

Comment: It should be possible to access the name via `((ManagementObject)managementBaseObject)["Name"]` and use that instead of `.ToString()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of letting the compiler choose the base type `ManagementBaseObject`, you can specify that you only want all `ManagementObject`instances in the collection.

```
foreach (ManagementObject instance in searcher.Get())
```

This way you do not need to cast explicitely again.

To access any property of such a `ManagementObject` use the [string] access notation. The string has to be the property name, in your case it would be `Name`.

```
Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", instance["Name"]);
```

The full code would be:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(new SelectQuery("Win32_UserAccount"));

foreach (ManagementObject instance in searcher.Get())
{
    var strUsername = instance["Name"];
    Console.WriteLine("Username: {0}", strUsername);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually did this already finding it on another question, but I'll accept your answer as it did work.